# How do I merge 2 partitions on AWS after expanding the volume and filesystem on linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, partition, amazon-ebs

I have the original volume showing at 8GB on the default instance when i created it on AWS. Then I went through the process of expanding the existing volume to 500GB and then expanding the filesystem (as instructed in the AWS procedures). It seems there are still 2 volumes and Im having trouble because Im limited by the original 8GB as its not seeing the other 500GB. How can I merge these? I've attached the lsblk and df -h command results and the screenshots from the AWS console for that volume.  According to the aws the console only has 1 volume {...0f6 mounted dev/sda1 of size 500GB}.  But then when I go to volumes there are 2 volumes, one of 8GB (the original one i expanded) and another of 500GB which was the volume i expanded to!

How do I merge these so I dont keep getting out of disk space errors?

UPDATE: Filesystem type df -hT:
[image: fs type]

[image: sudo df -h]
[image: lsblk]
[image: aws instance volume]
[image: aws volume details 1]
[image: aws volume details 2]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the request, but it seems like your goal is to expand the 8 gb volume to 500 gb. The 2nd volume and instance is unnecessary for that since you can follow the procedures for AWS to expand the 8 GB Volume and then follow the OS procedures for Ubuntu to increase the partition size and file system size which would resolve your out of space issue. You can't merge two volumes as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Based on your screenshots, it looks like you did increase the volume from 8 gb to 500 gb and all you need to do is follow the steps based on ubuntu documentation to increase the partition size and file system size.

Comment: I did follow these steps outlined by AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html  Im not sure what it is that I missed...

Comment: I think you missed increasing the file system size. The partition nvme0n1p1 is 499 gb . If you're not sure what type of filesystem you have I'd check /etc/fstab to see what root is mounted as. Then you'll need to run the applicable command based off that. Xfs_growfs only works for xfs file systems.

Comment: I did extend the filesystem.  As you can see the partition is equal to the volume size.  Partition size 499GB, volume size 500GB.  The problems is that it seems there is another volume somehow attached to the instance as evidenced by the aws console snapshots, but not in the SSH shots.  When I log into SSH i can see it welcomes me and says I am using 99% of 8GB. space after runnning the sudo df -h command.  But when running the lsblk command you can see the partition is 500GB.

Comment: No, my filesystem is not xfs so I had to use growfs.  Anyway, Ill try again.  I just uploaded an image of the df -hT command.

Comment: Partition size is not the same thing as the filesystem size. The former resides in the partition table, the latter resides in the partition itself (i.e., filesystem metadata). (Not sure what you mean by growfs; for ext4 you should use resize2fs.)

Comment: I just wanted to add that the two volumes appear to be attached to different instances indicated in your last screenshot.